# Input of maximum 256 characters in C

Tags: c, io, fgets, getc

I/O question:

I was asked to get an input from the user and parse it.
The problem is my program is supposed to be able to handle *any* length of input and to treat any input line longer than 256 characters as invalid and print a message accordingly.

Currently I'm using `fgets` to recieve the input line and `strtok` to parse it later on, but it's a problem with a very long input line.

How could I solve this problem?

my code so far:

```
char userInput[1024];
        char *token = NULL;

        while (!feof(stdin)) {
                    fflush(stdin);
                    if (fgets(userInput, 1024, stdin) != NULL) {
                    token = strtok(userInput, " \t\r\n");
                        if (token != NULL) {



                            if (strncmp(userInput, "fiver", 5) == 0) {

                                            printf("5");
                                            }
                            else if (strncmp(userInput, "four", 4) == 0) { printf("4");}
```

Comment: [`fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have an array or 257 or 258 characters (depending on whether to count the newline among those 256) and read into it using `fgets`, passing in the size 257 or 258. Then check the length of the string with `strlen()`. If the `strlen(buf)` is exactly the maximum length of the line *including* the newline, then check the `strlen(buf)-1`th character - if it is `\n` it is fine, otherwise you've got a too long line.

---

Or just use `fgetc` instead of `fgets`, counting until `'\n'` or 256 whichever comes first.